# I want to append javascript code in script tag

Tags: javascript

I am using plain javascript , what i want to achieve is , i am using squarespace and they are using jquery cdn for backend but there jquery cdn is not available in frontend , so if we add jquery in backend then there will be conflict so what i am doing is i am adding check that when squarespace dont have squarespace editable class then i am adding jquery cdn and after adding jquery cdn i am adding jquery code . jquery cdn is appended but jquery code is not appending in the script tag that is where i am stuck ,

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {    
if(document.body.classList.contains('squarespace-editable'))
 {
  document.getElementById("jquerscript").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"; 
  document.getElementById("jquerscriptCode").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
 }
 else
 {
  var newScripttwo = document.createElement("script");
  newScripttwo.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js";
  document.getElementById("jquerscript").appendChild(newScripttwo);                    
  newScript = document.createElement("script");
  newScript.onload = function () {
    alert('checking');
  }

  document.getElementById("jquerscriptCode").appendChild(newScript);        
}
```

});

these are two empty div's i am appending javascript code to

```
<div id="jquerscript"></div>
<div id="jquerscriptCode"></div>
```

in the jquerscriptCode script tag is appending but the code i am trying to append in between the script tag is not working .

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("jquerscript").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!"; 

document.getElementById("jquerscriptCpde").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
```

You wrote code with p (jquerscriptCpde)
So change it to o (jquerscriptCode), i think thats your problem, if it didn't solve tell me to read your code again and check for more..